# How to allow users to access my Google API application without authenticating for it?

Tags: javascript, html, json, oauth, google-sheets-api

I've developed a small webapp, that pulls raw data from a [Google Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NmQVCBxisQHm5VFNxx7kzw007r2i75XjgNzP5hsB-zE/edit#gid=0) and builds it on a [html](http://vaipradisney.com/homolog/ferramentas/TrixPull/), so my website users can see, filter and navigate through the data.

For that, I'm using Google Sheets API v4, but even going to an HTML, users are asked to "AUTHORIZE" access using their Google Accounts, before seeing the table/data.

Is there a way to display this table/data on the HTML, without requesting users to authorize through OAuth?

Comment: maybe the permissions on the spreadsheet are wrong. You can give permission so that anyone using the link has access, with or without a google account.

Answer (score 0):

If you're dealing with accessing data and performing Google API calls, [authorization](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/http-auth) is Google's way to protect and secure the user's data.

If you want to display the data without needing to undergo authorization, [publish it to the web](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/37579?hl=en):

File -> Publish to the web. An embed code which contains a public url will be provided for you.

Here's a sample of my public data:

```
 https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mvFPT2Xx8bNEMUdPC9TDOexzNqVS399bxQATV3JVOyg/pubhtml?widget=true&amp
```